# what's solution of next html frame?

Tags: html

html frame will be not use in next html generation,,so, what the solution for next generation in case of frame?

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721929/when-should-i-use-html-frames

Answer (score 0):

Frames fell out of fashion about 6 months after they were introduced.

People have been using templates to include common content for even longer than they've been using CSS for layout.

… and HTML 5 still has [iframes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element).

Answer (score 0):

I too heard about that action. But still frames are working in HTML5 supported browsers. So, not to worry.

Html 4.x version's tag will work in HTML 5 supported browsers.

Also, if you have any PHP server, then PHP `require()` and `include()` are best action. It may be useful for headers and footers. PHP makes your website a little bit slow and overloads it. But just a little bit.

Comment: Hey, upvote and accept my answer, if you get every information you needed, from it.